# cant find variable on react native android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

So i'm new to react native and i just started to build a learning apps here is the code

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from "react-native";

import FetchLocation from "./components/FetchLocation";
export default class App extends React.Component {
  getUserLocationHandler = () => {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FetchLocation onGetLocation={this.getUserLocationHandler}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

**FetchLocation.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-native';

const fetchlocation = props => {
    return(
        <Button title="Get Location" onPress={props.onGetLocation} />
    );
};

export default fetchLocation;
```

this is an image of the [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxxVx.png)

and this is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MczY.jpg) of the error on my mobile

I dont think that this is complex problem, but it really frustate me.
Thank you

Comment: You have misspelled `fetchlocation` in your `FetchLocation.js` file. It should be with a capital `L`.

Comment: That's alright, it happens to all of us. I have voted to close this question as it's just a tiny typo, but you can also remove the question if you like.